# How to calculate the tipping point of complex objets (or combination of objects)

Tags: classical-mechanics

[image: Diagram of the setup]
I've designed this iPad holder (the yellow bit) to attach to my mechanical keyboard. I'm 3d-printing it hollow in order to fill up with whatever weight I might need. I don't want to overdo it, as that would defeat the purpose of making a more-or-less portable setup. So I'm wondering how I can calculate what the weight of the holder should be so that the setup is stable and won't risk tipping over easily.

I'm having some trouble figuring out how the math I'm finding online, as well as the online tipping calculators, should be applied to a more complex object/setup as this one.

I'm often wondering how these things are calculated, so this is actually more of an experimental project for me rather than just a DIY thing, otherwise I'd just fill it up with resin, test it, and then add, say, lead if needed. But I would like to learn how to calculate this, just for fun and for future projects. Which is why any guidance toward where I might find the info that will allow me to calculate this will be highly appreciated!

PS. A bit more on the diagram. It's all the (I assume) relevant bits of data. The green bits are where the holder is attached to the keyboard. The asterisk refers to the distante the iPad goes into the holder. I don't know the weight of the 3D-printed piece yet, I would calculate it at 0, to err on the side of caution.

Answer (score 2):

All else being equal, fixed assemblies tend to move spontaneously to lower their center of mass. What follows is a sequential approach for characterizing stability and stability robustness.

Locate the center of mass of your assembly.

Identify the six ways your assembly could move: translation in all three dimensions, rotation around all three orthogonal axes, subject to the constraints applied by the surroundings. For example, your assembly can't move down because it would run into the table. It could move straight up.

Plot how the center of mass would move for each of the six modes of motion. If the center of mass always rises, motion won't spontaneously occur. If motion is possible but the center of mass neither rises nor falls, motion could occur but would be damped by friction. If the center of mass falls, motion is spontaneous. If the center of mass rises or stays constant but then falls, the assembly is robust against small but not large disturbances; these cases need to be examined individually to determine whether a reasonable engineering (geometry or material) change would favorably increase stability robustness. The most obvious example is tipping backward from a slight nudge; I suspect that making the yellow region heavier won't change the center-of-mass trajectory much, but extending that yellow region farther backward would.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Now I have a starting point. :) (Yes, I thought extending backward was the more common-sense solution. But I wanted to keep the on-desk footprint as small as possible. Maybe I'll have to add a tail that can be extended if needed.) If you have any resource or reading material to recommend that might have more details/examples, that would be greatly appreciated.