# Finding the tipping force for a cantilever table

Tags: classical-mechanics, statics

[image: Cantilever Table]

How would I find the force it takes to the table to tip over if you were sit on top the cantilever end?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the tipping point of complex objets (or combination of objects)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/767850/how-to-calculate-the-tipping-point-of-complex-objets-or-combination-of-objects)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
We can look at the torque. We have a pivot point r that everything will go around. And we can see three forces $F_1$, $F_2$ and $F_3$. $F_1$ twisting one way (the sitter), $F_2$( the centre of mass of the stuff on the other side of the pivot), and $F_3$( The centre of mass on the right side of the table). If the table is stable, all torques( force times the perpendicular distance to the pivot) one way should equal the torques the other way.
$$F_2x_2=F_1x_1+F_3x_3$$
So, for a tip to happen the right-hand side of the equation should be larger than the left so we get
$$F_2x_2<F_1x_1+F_3x_3$$
so we can take $F_3x_3$ on to the other side and divide by $x_1$
$$\frac{F_2x_2-F_3x_3}{x_1}<F_1$$
so finding the left-hand side will give us the force $F_1$ we need to be larger to begin tipping.